# Select Textbox using For Loop

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Sorry this is weird and silly question but I need a solution of this...
I have 30 textboxes named as Txt1,Txt2,Txt3,...,Txt30
I have to fill textbox as Txt1.text = 0 on button click..

Is there any way like
 On Button Click

```
Dim i as Integer
For i = 1 to 30  '----- Possible in string but don't know if possible in textboxes
Txt(i).text = 0
Next
```

Or I have to write all 30 lines like

```
Txt1.text = 0
...
Txt30.text = 0
```

I don't know how this question asked, maybe Question improper.
Thanx in Advance...

Comment: Are you talking of Winform's textboxes?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry I forgot Winform Tag... @Steve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the textboxes are all contained in Controls collection of the Form, then it is really easy to loop over them

```
For Each(t in Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)())
   t.Text = "0"
```

Of course the advantage of this approach is that you don't have to worry if you add other textboxes to your form. They will be found using the foreach loop without having a fixed top limit.

And, if not all of your textboxes should be included in the loop, then you can simply use the Tag property of the textboxes that you want to use. For example, if you set the Tag property to the string "Y", then you can change the foreach loop to find only the controls with the matching Tag property

```
For Each t in Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)() _ 
                         .Where(Function(x) x.Tag = "Y")
   t.Text = "0"
```

The two solutions above works well if all your textboxes are contained in the same container (Form, GroupBox or Panel), instead, if these textboxes are dispersed in different containers (some in a groupbox, others in a panel etc) then you can build a `List(Of TextBox)` variable filling it with the textboxes instances and use it when the need arise

```
Dim myTexts = New List(Of TextBox)() From  { Txt1, Txt2, Txt3, ....}
```

And loop over this variable

Comment: Ya all textboxes are in a single form...
I guess you got my question, just tell you after trying it.

Answer (score 5):

You can do as Steve said, but if you have other textboxes that you don't want to edit then there is another way:

```
For i = 1 to 30
    dim found = Me.Controls.Find("Txt" & i, True) '<- the True argument is for recursive search
    If Not IsNothing(found) AndAlso found.Length > 0 Then
        found(0).Text = "0"
    End If
Next
```

If your textboxes are all in the same control, for example `GroupBox`, you can do `GroupBox.Controls.Find` saving CPU resources

Comment: Text is not member of Control()... Showing me this.! error on "Found.text = 0"

Comment: It's true, that's because `Find()` returns an array. I edited the code

Comment: I sent you an email but was rejected x_x It appears your email domain is expired